# Prevent action from Laravel observer events

Tags: php, laravel, observers, laravel-5.6, php-7.2

I would like to know how an action could be prevented on a model observer, for example:

```
$model->update(['foo' => 'bar']);
```

In the observer

```
public function updating(Model $model)
{
    if($model->isDirty('foo') {
        // Prevent action from happening
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply return false.

As mentioned in the docs. http://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events#defining-listeners.

> Sometimes, you may wish to stop the propagation of an event to other listeners. You may do so by returning false from your listener's handle method.

this action will not be updating the record/model.

```
public function updating(Model $model)
{
    if ($model->isDirty('foo')) {
       // Prevent action from happening
       return false;
    }
}
```

Although model instance values gets updated but these are not updated in database so beware while returning the instance to views or APIs. To cater this problem you can use `getOriginal()`

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's so simple, but i didn't find it anywhere, do you know any resource where this is mentioned? Thank you very much

Comment: @Asur If you dig into source  you will find one. :D

Comment: @Asur although model instance values gets updated but these are not updated in database so beware while returning the instance to views or APIs

Comment: You can check it [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getOriginal)

Comment: This is mentioned in the docs @ https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events#defining-listeners. `Stopping The Propagation Of An Event - Sometimes, you may wish to stop the propagation of an event to other listeners. You may do so by returning false from your listener's handle method.`

Comment: Now in 2022, this doesn't seem to work. Looks like you have to use an [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers) instead.