# Eloquent event deleting listener return false will stop delete function? [laravel]

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have `Team` eloquent and `TeamObserver`. `TeamObserver` has `deleting event` and in the event i call `TeamDeletingEvent`. `TeamDeletingEvent` dispatch `TeamDeletingListener`. If `TeamDeletingLister` will return false will stop the team delete function?

TeamObserver

```
class TeamObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the team "deleting" event.
     *
     * @param  Team  $team
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleting(Team $team)
    {
        event(new TeamDeletingEvent($team));
    }
}
```

TeamDeletingEvent

```
class TeamDeletingEvent
{
    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var Team
     */
    public $team;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Team $team)
    {
        $this->team = $team;
    }
}
```

TeamDeletingListener

```
class TeamDeletingListener
{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  TeamDeletingEvent  $event
     * @return bool
     */
    public function handle(TeamDeletingEvent $event)
    {
        $teamUser = Team::where('id', $event->team->id)->users()->first();
        if(is_null($teamUser)){
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

More than this `TeamObserver` registered in `AppServiceProvider` and `Event and Listener` registered in `EventServiceProvider`

Comment: Just a quick heads up that you can refactor the `if` in your listener's `handle` method to: `return $teamUser === null`.

Comment: And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50016540/8394877) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listener return false will not stop the delete function. It will stop the continuous listener call of the event. But Eloquent event returning false will stop the delete function. (model instance values gets updated but these are not updated in database). More info [Detail Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016476/prevent-action-from-laravel-observer-events/50016540#50016540)